# Error when storing a publisher in an AnyCancellable's Set

Tags: swift, collections, combine, dylib

Some users are getting this error in the app when storing a Cancellable in a `Set` using the `AnyCancellable.store(in:)` method. The error maybe happens to a 10% of the users and I can't really replicate it.

This is a simplified version of the code:

```
    private var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()
    private func doSomeWork() {
        doMoreWork() {
            DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
                guard let self = self else { return }

                service.valuesPublisher
                    .sink { [weak self] something in
                        self?.doSomeWork(something)
                    }
                    .store(in: &self.cancellables)
            }
        }
```

And the error's log is the following:

```
Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Triggered by Thread:  0

Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x193a3cd78 __exceptionPreprocess + 220 (NSException.m:200)
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x1ac6a1734 objc_exception_throw + 60 (objc-exception.mm:565)
2   CoreFoundation                  0x193b1ab88 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 144 (NSObject.m:147)
3   CoreFoundation                  0x1939d1988 ___forwarding___ + 1764 (NSForwarding.m:3577)
4   CoreFoundation                  0x1939d0a60 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 96
5   libswiftCore.dylib              0x1986312fc __CocoaDictionary.lookup(_:) + 56
6   Combine                         0x1aba3d5ec specialized Set._Variant.insert(_:) + 104 (<compiler-generated>:0)
7   Combine                         0x1aba5a024 AnyCancellable.store(in:) + 48 (<compiler-generated>:0)
```

I have no idea why this could happen, any hints?

Comment: Could you share the relevant code?

Comment: Added the code sample

Comment: Your code example should actually work. However, I am surprised that you execute your Combine code in an asynchronous block. In my opinion, this is not necessary because Combine is executed asynchronously anyway.

Comment: I edited my question because I didn't make it clear, I get this error randomly and I can't replicate it. I also updated the code.

Comment: faced with the same problem